# 8 Puzzle A* java Implemenation

Tags: java, shortest-path, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am told that A* implementation on following 8 puzzle Solver is wrong, can anybody please tell me where it's wrong and how to correct it?

Also: this throws ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*** even though Build Process Heap size is set to 2048.

Here is Solver.java

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;


public class Solver {
private int moves = 0;
private SearchNode finalNode;
private Stack<Board> boards;


public Solver(Board initial) {
    if (!initial.isSolvable()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsolvable puzzle");

    // this.initial = initial;
    PriorityQueue<SearchNode> minPQ = new PriorityQueue<SearchNode>(initial.size() + 10);

    Set<Board> previouses = new HashSet<Board>(50);
    Board dequeuedBoard = initial;
    Board previous = null;
    SearchNode dequeuedNode = new SearchNode(initial, 0, null);
    Iterable<Board> boards;

    while (!dequeuedBoard.isGoal()) {
        boards = dequeuedBoard.neighbors();
        moves++;

        for (Board board : boards) {
            if (!board.equals(previous) && !previouses.contains(board)) {
                minPQ.add(new SearchNode(board, moves, dequeuedNode));
            }
        }

        previouses.add(previous);
        previous = dequeuedBoard;
        dequeuedNode = minPQ.poll();
        dequeuedBoard = dequeuedNode.current;
    }
    finalNode = dequeuedNode;
}

// min number of moves to solve initial board
public int moves() {
    if (boards != null) return boards.size()-1;
    solution();
    return boards.size() - 1;
}

public Iterable<Board> solution() {
    if (boards != null) return boards;
    boards = new Stack<Board>();
    SearchNode pointer = finalNode;
    while (pointer != null) {
        boards.push(pointer.current);
        pointer = pointer.previous;
    }
    return boards;
}

private class SearchNode implements Comparable<SearchNode> {
    private final int priority;
    private final SearchNode previous;
    private final Board current;


    public SearchNode(Board current, int moves, SearchNode previous) {
        this.current = current;
        this.previous = previous;
        this.priority = moves + current.manhattan();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SearchNode that) {
        int cmp = this.priority - that.priority;
        return Integer.compare(cmp, 0);
    }


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] tiles = {{4, 1, 3},
            {0, 2, 6},
            {7, 5, 8}};



    double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Board board = new Board(tiles);
    Solver solve = new Solver(board);
    System.out.printf("# of moves = %d && # of actual moves %d & time passed %f\n, ", solve.moves(), solve.moves, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000);


}
}
```

And Board.java, just in case:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;


public final class Board {

    private final int[][] tilesCopy;
    private final int N;

    // cache
    private int hashCode = -1;
    private int zeroRow = -1;
    private int zeroCol = -1;
    private Collection<Board> neighbors;
    /*
     * Rep Invariant
     *      tilesCopy.length > 0
     * Abstraction Function
     *      represent single board of 8 puzzle game
     * Safety Exposure
     *      all fields are private and final (except cache variables). In the constructor,
     * defensive copy of tiles[][] (array that is received from the client)
     * is done.
     */
    public Board(int[][] tiles) {
        //this.N = tiles.length;
        this.N = 3;
        this.tilesCopy = new int[N][N];
        // defensive copy
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (tiles[i][j] >= 0 && tiles[i][j] < N*N) tilesCopy[i][j] = tiles[i][j];
                else {
                    System.out.printf("Illegal tile value at (%d, %d): "
                            + "should be between 0 and N^2 - 1.", i, j);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
        checkRep();
    }

    public int tileAt(int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row > N - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
                ("row should be between 0 and N - 1");
        if (col < 0 || col > N - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
                ("col should be between 0 and N - 1");

        return tilesCopy[row][col];
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    public int hamming() {
        int hamming = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < this.size(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.size(); col++) {
                if (tileAt(row, col) != 0 && tileAt(row, col) != (row*N + col + 1)) hamming++;
            }
        }
        return hamming;
    }
    // sum of Manhattan distances between tiles and goal
    public int manhattan() {
        int manhattan = 0;

        int expectedRow = 0, expectedCol = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < this.size(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.size(); col++) {
                if (tileAt(row, col) != 0 && tileAt(row, col) != (row*N + col + 1)) {
                    expectedRow = (tileAt(row, col) - 1) / N;
                    expectedCol = (tileAt(row, col) - 1) % N;
                    manhattan += Math.abs(expectedRow - row) + Math.abs(expectedCol - col);
                }
            }
        }
        return manhattan;
    }

    public boolean isGoal() {

        if (tileAt(N-1, N-1) != 0) return false;        // prune

        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++) {
                if (tileAt(i, j) != 0 && tileAt(i, j) != (i*N + j + 1)) return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    // change i && j' s name
    public boolean isSolvable() {
        int inversions = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.size() * this.size(); i++) {
            int currentRow = i / this.size();
            int currentCol = i % this.size();

            if (tileAt(currentRow, currentCol) == 0) {
                this.zeroRow = currentRow;
                this.zeroCol = currentCol;
            }

            for (int j = i; j < this.size() * this.size(); j++) {
                int row = j / this.size();
                int col = j % this.size();


                if (tileAt(row, col) != 0 && tileAt(row, col) < tileAt(currentRow, currentCol)) {
                    inversions++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (tilesCopy.length % 2 != 0 && inversions % 2 != 0) return false;
        if (tilesCopy.length % 2 == 0 && (inversions + this.zeroRow) % 2 == 0) return false;

        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object y) {
        if (!(y instanceof Board)) return false;
        Board that = (Board) y;
        // why bother checking whole array, if last elements aren't equals
        return this.tileAt(N - 1, N - 1) == that.tileAt(N - 1, N - 1) && this.size() == that.size() && Arrays.deepEquals(this.tilesCopy, that.tilesCopy);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (this.hashCode != -1) return hashCode;
        // more optimized version(Arrays.hashCode is too slow)?
        this.hashCode = Arrays.deepHashCode(tilesCopy);
        return this.hashCode;
    }

    public Collection<Board> neighbors() {
        if (neighbors != null) return neighbors;
        if (this.zeroRow == -1 && this.zeroCol == -1) findZeroTile();

        neighbors = new HashSet<>();

        if (zeroRow - 1 >= 0)           generateNeighbor(zeroRow - 1, true);
        if (zeroCol - 1 >= 0)           generateNeighbor(zeroCol - 1, false);
        if (zeroRow + 1 < this.size())  generateNeighbor(zeroRow + 1, true);
        if (zeroCol + 1 < this.size())  generateNeighbor(zeroCol + 1, false);

        return neighbors;
    }

    private void findZeroTile() {
        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++) {
                if (tileAt(i, j) == 0) {
                    this.zeroRow = i;       // index starting from 0
                    this.zeroCol = j;
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void generateNeighbor(int toPosition, boolean isRow) {
        int[][] copy = Arrays.copyOf(this.tilesCopy, tilesCopy.length);
        if (isRow)  swapEntries(copy, zeroRow, zeroCol, toPosition, zeroCol);
        else        swapEntries(copy, zeroRow, zeroCol, zeroRow, toPosition);

        neighbors.add(new Board(copy));
    }


    private void swapEntries(int[][] array, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
        int i = array[fromRow][fromCol];
        array[fromRow][fromCol] = array[toRow][toCol];
        array[toRow][toCol] = i;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(4 * N * N);     // optimization?
//      s.append(N + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                s.append(String.format("%2d ", tileAt(i, j)));
            }
            s.append("\n");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    private void checkRep() {
        assert tilesCopy.length > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: On first sight I must agree that I don't see a problem for a 3 by 3 puzzle. But there is room for improvement. For instance start with not having a neighbors collection on your board, this keeps a reference to it and prevents the garbage collector from cleaning up + additional memory for storing a HashSet for each board. worst case about (9! / 2) additional hashsets

Comment: And add the board to previouses set at the time is created instead of when is processed. The same board will be processed multiple times

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand what you mean. Sorry

Comment: @SamSegers Do you see any problem in this method: public Solver(Board initial) ?

Comment: Don't you think you should reduce your problem to a more, simple case? What would you learn, if we find out? Which line triggers the oom-error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is at line

```
int[][] copy = Arrays.copyOf(this.tilesCopy, tilesCopy.length);
```

You assume here to have copied the matrix. But actually you've copied the array with references to arrays in the 2nd dimension. 
In other words

```
copy == this.tolesCopy // false
copy[0] == this.tilesCopy[0] // true
copy[1] == this.tilesCopy[1] // true
copy[2] == this.tilesCopy[2] // true
```

what leads to have the same matrix changed multiple times, and even to an invalid/unsolvable state.
The easiest fix I see in your code would be to change the generateNeighbor method

```
private void generateNeighbor(int toPosition, boolean isRow) {
    Board board = new Board(this.tilesCopy);
    if (isRow)  swapEntries(board.tilesCopy, zeroRow, zeroCol, toPosition, zeroCol);
    else        swapEntries(board.tilesCopy, zeroRow, zeroCol, zeroRow, toPosition);

    neighbors.add(board);
}
```

Although the overal idea looks good. There are multiple other things that can be improved. I suggest you to have a look at [this implementation](https://github.com/Samjayyy/logicpuzzles/tree/master/eightpuzzle)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.